# MSTest library error on a CI pipeline of TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server

Good morning,

We are developing an MSTest project and we want to upload it to our TFS server that has a Build pipeline configured. The project has been developed with an VS 2017 Enterprise Edition, obviously. The problem is that when we try to make the upload the CI process is launched and gives us the following error:

```
[error] Web_MSTest \ CodedUITestProject1 \ CodedUITest1.cs (10,51): Error CS0234: The type or name of the namespace 'UITesting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools' (missing any assembly reference?)
```

And, therefore, all the methods in this library fail. Is this because the build server must also have an Enterprise version of VS installed in order to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to install VS Enterprise and check that CodedUI was included to it.

You may try to use **Visual Studio Test Platform Installer**. This step`ll add test packages to your environment. In this case you may try to run your tests without VS. Check this link (section NOTE): [Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=azure-devops#arguments)

Additionally, check these news: [Use UI automation to test your code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2019)

> Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where Coded UI Test will be available. We recommend using Selenium for testing web apps and Appium with WinAppDriver for testing desktop and UWP apps.

Maybe you`ll choose another test platform.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, I wanted to use Selenium instead, but I work in IT consultancy and my client wanted a POC...

Comment: @Lagudose I`ve updated my answer. Try to use "Visual Studio Test Platform Installer" to install test components without VS.